# Reputation frozen?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, reputation

I started this day with reputation of 595. Durung the day several of my answers were upvoted quite a few times. But my reputation the whole day stayed planted firmly at precisely 595. No changes whatsoever. Is there something I'm missing about the way it is calculated? I thought it is supposed to go up as you get upvoted. (And that's the way it worked for me before.)

Comment: Should be on meta.  ... But, you probably hit your 200 cap after midnight GMT, so your rep probably already had the max 200 points before you started answering today.

Comment: @Reed, 200 cap? where can I read more about?

Comment: @Rubens Farias: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: The proof: http://stackoverflow.com/users/recent/187690?StartDate=2009-10-14&EndDate=2009-10-14

Answer (score 6):

You already hit the [reputation cap of 200](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) today. You can see this using [Jon Skeet's reputation tracker](http://csharpindepth.com/StackOverflow/ReputationTracker.aspx?so=187690&sf=&su=&meta=&mode=today), or using SO by going to [your recent activity page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/recent/187690?StartDate=2009-10-14&EndDate=2009-10-14).

Answer (score 3):

You hit your 200 limit cap. Meaning you can only get 200 rep in a day (not counting bounties)

Comment: What about this user: http://stackoverflow.com/users/189450/someone ?

Comment: @cetnar: that's an interesting case, that.  member for 1 day, 381 rep, 5 bronze and 1 silver badge.  Hmm....

Comment: @retracile - if you check his rep graph and set the start and end dates to 2009/10/13 you can see he earned 180 points yesterday and another 200 today. The "member for 1 day" is only approximate it seems.

Comment: @chrisf - makes sense... and I could see the 'signed up at' time being used to calculate membership time, so it could still be less than 24hrs, even though he's on day 2 of rep counting.

Comment: ... and accepted answers.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe some of your answers are now community-wiki.